# Determining the type of an expression

Tags: c++, c

Sometimes I need to learn the type of an expression while programming in C or C++. Sometimes there's a good IDE or existent documentation to help me, but sometimes not. I often feel such a construct could be useful:

```
void (*myFunc)(int);
printf("%s", nameoftype(myFunc)); //"void (*)(int)"
int i, unsigned int u;
printf("%s", nameoftype(i+u));    //"unsigned int"
```

This is especially true for C++; think accessors of const objects - do they return a const reference or a copy? Think dynamic casts and templated classes.

How can I do this? (i.e. learn the type of an expression)

I use GCC but as far as I know, it does not have such an extension. So I guess I'm curious as to how people solve this problem. (Both compile-time and runtime solutions welcome.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you looking for? Automatic type inference or looking for the type so you can declare a variable correctly manually? (your own answers look like you want to have the second one). In this case, consider using [Geordi](https://github.com/Eelis/geordi):

```
<litb> make type pointer to function taking pointer to array of 10 int returning void
<geordi> void (*)(int (*)[10])

<litb> geordi: { int a = -1; unsigned int b = 0; cout << ETYPE(a + b), ETYPE_DESC(a + b), (a + b); }
<geordi> rvalue unsigned int, rvalue unsigned integer, 4294967295

<litb> geordi: << TYPE_DESC(void (*)(int (*)[10]))
<geordi> pointer to a function taking a pointer to an array of 10 integers and returning nothing
```

Automatic type inference is not currently possible without helper libraries like boost.typeof, which will use compiler extensions like `__typeof__` for GCC. Next C++ will get `auto` (with different semantics than current `auto`) and will be able to do that, together with `decltype` to get the type of an expression.

If you can live with getting out of local context, you can always create a function template like this:

```
template<typename T> void f(T t) { /* ... */ }
int main() { int a = -1; unsigned int b = 0; f(a + b); }
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was obvious I wasn't looking for type inference. Though I'm looking forward to seeing some new sphagetti C++0x code with automatic variables all around :) -- Wow, I'd forgotten Geordi could do type descriptions. I'll have a look at the implementation. Also thanks for the KDevelop link. It might make an alternative to Eclipse.

Comment: Geordi link is dead - here is the current location on github: https://github.com/Eelis/geordi

Answer (score 21):

Sometimes I just do:

```
int ***a = expression;
```

and look for the "<expression type> cannot be assigned to pointer-to^3 int" error. This seems to be the most portable workaround.

Comment: Some older C compilers will actually allow that though. :-(

Comment: I create a class 'FailAssign' then try to assign an expression to a instance of the class. That way no auto  conversions kick in ( even buggy ones).

Comment: Hmm, good idea. Though my way lets you declare a triple pointer! How often do you get to do that? :)

Answer (score 3):

C++ has a `typeid` operator;

```
typeid(expression).name()
```

would return an implementation-defined name of the type of the expression. Alas, it is usually not human-readable.

Comment: If youare using g++ it is the mangeled name. You can then use the command line tool 'c++filt' to de-mangle it.

Comment: Currently this approach is not recommended, and should be considered in some case deprecated. The reason it though it prints type, the type output is cumbersome. Moreover sometimes it prints invalid type! The exact examples are clearly explained in new "Effective Modern C++", Chapter 1, Item 4.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Boost.Typeof](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/typeof.html) to see if it fits.

Comment: It seems like a good solution for type inference, but I did not see a macro that evaluates to, or a function that returns a string containing the type name. One could be added, though, seeing as how it uses central REGISTER_() macros.

Answer (score 1):

gcc has typeof() at compile time.  It works like sizeof().

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html has more information.