# What is the return type of this expression in C?

Tags: c

> If `i` is an `int` variable and `f` is a `float` variable, what is the type of the conditional expression `(i > 0 ? i : f)`?

Consider any arbitrary value of `i` because I just want to know the type of the expression. I am not getting how can we check the type of this expression because if we store the result in an `int` variable, we get the output as integer and if the result is stored in a `float` variable, the output is `float`.

Question taken from K. N. King book.

Comment: Quote what you want to quote in text, not in an image that's also rotated.

Comment: I quoted it what was mentioned in the image .

Comment: This image is blinding!

Comment: You can test it with simple `printf`.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: How? Are you referring to the warnings that *some* compilers issue for `printf` type mismatches?

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, I am referring to some compiler, and undefined behaviors that one can see. Yes, I know the arguments. But for a simple testing, invoking UB to see something is just fine, as it is pretty predictable.

Comment: @Eugene Sh.: I see don't see how it is useful, especially taking into account that variadic arguments are implicitly converted, which obfuscates their true type.

Comment: Why exactly are you asking this? The picture you initially posted of in your book even explicitly says, "the expression has type float."

Comment: @AnT I personally wasn't very sure and just did it in a minute instead of digging for relevant standard paragraph (actually I wasn't sure it will compile). So it was quite useful to me.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: bolov's suggestion of using it to initialize an `int***` object seems more reliable. Unlike a `printf` type mismatch, a diagnostic is required, and is at least as likely to mention the type of the expression.

Comment: @KeithThompson That one is interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **6.5.15 Conditional operator**, paragraph 4:

> If both the second and third operands have arithmetic type, the result type that would be determined by the usual arithmetic conversions, were they applied to those two operands, is the type of the result.

And then in **6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions**, paragraph 1:

> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `float`, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is `float`.

Therefore, the type of the expression is `float`.

Comment: Here we are doing comparison between variable i and 0 in i > 0 , so how can we say that type of resultant would be float ?

Comment: @radhika: The comparison (i.e. the condition) is not used to determine the type of the expression. In other words, it does not matter what you write as the first operand of the conditional operator. Moreover, it does not matter what the value of `i` nor `f` is.

Comment: Also , it is similar to returning either a float value of or an int value depending on the conditional expression evaluation so when no comparison is done between int and float how can we say common type is float ?

Comment: @radhika: C is a statically typed language. This means that the types of expressions are pre-determined at compilation time. In other words: you cannot change types when running the program; nor there are several types for a single expression. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Getting inspired by [Determining the type of an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829623/determining-the-type-of-an-expression):

```
void test()
{
    int i = 0;
    float f = 0.;

    int ***a = i > 0 ? i : f;
}
```

> error: initializing 'int ***' with an expression of incompatible type
>   'float'
>
> ```
> int ***a = i > 0 ? i : f;
>        ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

So the type is `float`.

The `printf` method suggested is unreliable as in varargs `float` gets promoted to `double`.

As for the reasoning there is already another answer with quotes from the standard mentioning common type so I won't repeat it here.

Comment: True, but compilers aren't required to tell you the type. The only requirement from the standard is that a diagnostic must be issued. (Most compilers will try to be informative.)

Comment: @KeithThompson of course. I just used it get a confirmation from a compiler. Since it worked I got my confirmation. Actually what I tried first got me an error which didn't tell the type. It's a method that doesn't guarantee it works, but when it works (and it usually works on modern compilers) it guarantees to give you the correct answer (modulo a compiler bug).

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int i=0;
   double f=1.0;
   printf("%d\n",i>0?i:f);
   return 0;
}
```

gcc version 6.3.0,  compile with -Wall

```
warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]
  printf("%d\n",i>0?i:f);
```

so the type of (condition?int:float) is float

Comment: incorrect answer. In varargs arguments float gets promoted to double so it's unreliable. It's also what is happening here.

Comment: when you compare i> 0 that is false so the condition returns the value of the variable f which is double type, that is why the compile shows you that warning if you define f as an int you should be able to solve that problem

Comment: @root-kidz no, set i=1 and you'll get exactly the same warning

Comment: @root-kidz The type of a conditional expression depends on the types of the second and third operands, not on the (run-time) value of the first.

Comment: Yes, you've shown us the warning message, but you haven't answered the question. The warning message refers to the promoted type (`double`). The type of the expression is `float`. You mention that (I think that was a recent edit), but you don't indicate how you concluded that from the warning -- and in fact you can't.